# How to DELETE "overflow-x" compeletly

Tags: css

Instead of hiding the `overflow-x` What can we do for deleting compeletly this ?

Because the page can be scrolled again but it's just get hidden.

I want to DELETE this .

What to do ?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong issue. Is there no way to ensure that content doesn't exist in the first place?

Comment: @JohnTobin there are many codes, and can't be solved any way, so i need something diffrent to solve this.

Comment: You need to give a code example - most likely you have a horizontal scroll caused by a container which has more than 100% width of the browser window. You need to tackle this issue first. You do not need to do overflow-x: hidden as it will cut off your content.

Answer (score 1):

you can use in your css code `overflow:hidden;`
you can also set the x value by scrollLeft in css.
for example

```
    <div style="overflow:hidden;height:50px;" onscroll="return false;">
    asdsad<br />
    asdsad<br />
    asdsad<br />
    sadsad<br />
    asdsad<br />
    </div>
```

other way just set a "div" box that enclose your tag and give height and width to it..

Comment: tnx, nut not working ! + i just want to disable "overflow-x"